# What is the role of impredicativity in program extraction?

Tags: coq, foundations, predicativity, program-extraction, realizability

Is impredicativity useful for program extraction in Coq? For example is there some kind of [realizability](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/realizability) argument that depends on impredicativity?

Of course it doesn't seem to be necessary for program extraction, as Agda manages to extract programs to Haskell, but I suspect there might be some kind of theoretical tradeoff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have occasionally thought about this question. My inconclusive conclusion is that impredicativity *hinders* program extraction. Let me try to give an argument in the context of realizability. I am going to crank up the technical level of the discussion, because the concepts involved are, well, a bit technical (but they also embody some pretty concrete intuitions).

Assume we're working in a realizability topos over a pca $\mathbb{A}$. Now, that's a pretty big and complicated category, which among other things contains $\mathsf{Set}$ as a full subcategory: given any set $X$, we get an object $\nabla X = (X, {\Vdash_{\nabla X}})$ in the topos whose realizability relation is trivial: $r \Vdash_{\nabla X} x$ holds for all $r \in \mathbb{A}$ and all $x \in X$. From a computational point of view the realizers of $\nabla X$ are maximally uninformative because every realizer $r$ realizes every element of $X$.

So if the realizability topos can contain such computationally trivial objects, perhaps we should try to define precisely what it means for an object to be computationally trivial in general.

Here is a bad attempt: say that an object $S$ of the topos is computationally trivial if every morphism $S \to \mathsf{Bool}$ is constant, where $\mathsf{Bool} = 1 + 1$ is the object of Booleans. The idea is right, namely $S$ should be considered computationally trivial if we can't extract any interesting bits of information from it, but the execution is wrong, because sometimes we can extract *less* than one bit. (For instance, we can't *decide* whether any given machine halts, but we can *semi-decide* that it halts.)

Given any disjoint non-empty subsets $T_0, T_1 \subseteq \mathbb{A}$ define the **test object** $[T_0, T_1]$ to be the set $\{0,1\}$ with the realizability relation
$$r \Vdash_{[T_0, T_1]} b \iff (r \in T_1 \land b = 1) \lor (r \in T_0 \land b = 0).
$$
In words, $1$ is realized by the elements of $T_1$ and $0$ by the elements of $T_0$. Examples:

- **Decidable test:** $T_0 = \{\mathtt{false}\}$ and $T_1 = \{\mathtt{true}\}$ yields the booleans,
- **Semi-decidable test:** $T_0 = \{\ulcorner M \urcorner \mid \text{machine $M$ does not halt on input $\ulcorner M \urcorner$}\}$ and $T_1 = \{\ulcorner M \urcorner \mid \text{machine $M$ halts on input $\ulcorner M \urcorner$}\}$.
- We can make much weaker notions of test than decidability and semi-decidability. Write $\mathsf{PA} \models \phi$ if the sentence $\phi$ in the language of Peano arithmetic is true, and define $$T_0 = \{ \ulcorner \phi \urcorner \mid \mathsf{PA} \models \phi\}$$ and $$T_1 = \{ \ulcorner \phi \urcorner \mid \mathsf{PA} \models \lnot\phi \}.$$ This sort of test is *very weak*. It is not about deciding arithmetical sentences, but rather *expresing* conditions with arithmetical formulas. Indeed, suppose $r \Vdash_{[T_0, T_1]} b$. Then $r$ encodes some arithmetical sentence $\phi$ such that $b = 1 \Leftrightarrow \mathsf{PA} \models \phi$ – so telling which bit $r$ encodes is as hard as computing arithmetical truth.

A morphism $f : S \to [T_0, T_1]$ can be thought of as a two-valued test.

> **Definition:** An object $S$ of the realizability topos is **computationally trivial** if for all test objects $[T_0, T_1]$ all morphisms $S \to [T_0, T_1]$ are constant.

What the definition says is that one cannot extract *any* non-trivial information from $S$, for *any* notion of two-valued test.

> **Proposition:** *For any set $X$, the object $\nabla X$ is computationally trivial.*

Here is the punchline: impredicativity is intimately tied to completeness, bu completeness prevents extraction of any useful information.

> **Theorem:** *A complete lattice is computationally trivial.*

*Proof.* We already know that $\nabla \{0,1\}$ is computationally trivial. Now consider any complete lattice $L$, a test object $[T_0, T_1]$ and a morphism $f : L \to [T_0, T_1]$. Given $x \in L$, define $g : \nabla \{0,1\} \to L$ by
$$g(p) = \sup \{ y \in L \mid y = x \land p = 1 \}$$
The map $f \circ g : \nabla \{0,1\} \to [T_0, T_1]$ is constant, therefore
$$f(\bot) = f(g(0)) = f(g(1)) = f(x),$$
which shows that $f$ is constant. $\Box$

P.S. A comment for the connoisseurs: all the above says is that all morphisms from a complete lattice to a modest set are constant.

Comment: This is a fascinating answer.

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer! I don't know much about realizability toposes, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I am having a hard time convincing myself that $g$ is well defined. For instance, if I take $L = \text{Bool}$, then $g$ must be constant, no? Or is $\text{Bool}$ not complete in this setting?

Comment: $\mathsf{Bool}$ is not complete in a realizability topos.